# Null Native Android Modules

Tags: android, react-native

I've followed the [official integration doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) and [Android Native Modules doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android).
I created a new module which seem to be null in RN code.
After some investigation I found out that I missed an @Override annotation, basically because It throws an error - `Method does not override method from its superclass`.
Here is my main activity which loads the bundle:

```
public class RnActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

   // @Override // <- Method does not override method from its superclass
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();
        // below MyAppPackage is added to the list of packages returned
        packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
        return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Activity currentActivity = this;
        final String Tag = "RnActivity";
        final String BUNDLE_NAME = getString(R.string.bundle_name);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SoLoader.init(this, false);
        try {
            mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(sApp.getApplicationContext());
            List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();
            // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
            // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            // Remember to include them in `settings.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` too.

            String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + BUNDLE_NAME;
            File file2 = new File(path);
            Log.d(Tag, "the path is: " + path);

            if (file2 != null && file2.exists()) {
                try {

                    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                            .setApplication(getApplication())
                            .setCurrentActivity(currentActivity)
                            .setJSBundleFile(path)
                            .addPackages(packages)
                            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                            .build();
                    // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
                    // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                }
            }
            mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", AppProps.getInitPropsBundle());
            setContentView(mReactRootView);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Tag,e.toString());
        }
    }
//... more irrelevant code
```

Since the method isn't overridden, MyAppPackage is never added (`packages.add(new MyAppPackage());`) and therefore my module is never registered:
*MyAppPackage.java:*

```
public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new NsClientAPI(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was solved successfully...
There is another way to add *MyAppPackage* so the problem stated above can be bypassed. Just add:

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                            .setApplication(getApplication())
                            .setCurrentActivity(currentActivity)
                            .setJSBundleFile(path)
                            .addPackages(packages)
                            .addPackage(new MyAppPackage()) // <- Added
                            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                            .build();
```

The solution was found thanks to [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-native-modules-in-react-native-android-hybrid-apps-62b67a2cc7ca).